# how can i make a filled textfield in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I saw this filled textfield on https://material.io/design/components/text-fields.html
but i don't know how to make it?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Okay, 
For the first example, you can use the following code snippet:

```
TextField(
        obscureText: false,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
          labelText: 'Password',
        ),
      )
```

And for the second example use snippet is given below:

```
TextField(
        obscureText: false,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
          labelText: 'Password',
        ),
      )
```

Hope this helps.

For more details and extended functionalities you can check the docs here: [Flutter Docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField-class.html)

Comment: can i add backgroundcolor to the first example?

Comment: Sure you can, just wrap the TextField in Container widget and set the color property of Container to the color of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

To get a filled textField, just do as shown below...

```
TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
        filled: true,
...
```

For more about [filled property of InputDecoration class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration/filled.html).

So, in case of any decoration of the textField or the textFormField or any components of them, go through the options provided by the InputDecoration and you may not need to wrap or pass any additional widgets.